# Where socket.io should be initialized in MERN?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, mern

I am working on a React project and following MERN boiler plate.In my project I am using socket.io for updating component state in real time. What is the most appropriate way of defining socket object in MERN so that it can be accessed through out application P.S : each component is defined in a separate .js file

I have different components defined in separate .js files
1. Home Page Component
2. Chat component:

I tried to define the socket.io object in Chat.js and have defined the callbacks in componentWillUpdate() function.This is working only if both users are on Chat page.

My usecase is : To send notification on Home Component when there is a new chat message in Chat Component

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please see my edit